# Excel Crashes When Calling Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I am trying to call an Oracle 19c stored procedure from Excel VBA.  I should preface by saying that I can query data without issue.  When the command is executed, Excel crashes.  Below is my code followed by the entry in the Event View.

```
Dim Oracon As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim objErr As ADODB.Error

Set Oracon = GetNewConnection

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = Oracon
    .CommandText = "SP_UPDATE_CLIENT_OPT_ISSUES"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .NamedParameters = True
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("NAN", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6, "100100")
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("OPTIMIZATION_ID", adNumeric, adParamInput, , 1)
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("DATE_OPENED", adDBDate, adParamInput, , Now)
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("DATE_CLOSED", adDBDate, adParamInput, , Now)
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("OPENED_BY", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, "Todd")
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("DESCRIPTION", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4000, "Test Description")
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("NOTES", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4000, "Test Note")
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("STATUS_UPDATE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4000, "This is a status update")
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("SR_NUMBER", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "3-1234567890")
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("ISSUE_TYPE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "Issue Type")
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("STATUS", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "Analysis")
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("SCREENSHOT", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, "c:\temp\test.png")
    .Execute
End With
```

The code for obtaining a database connection is:

```
Private Function GetNewConnection() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oCn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String


strConn = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home2_32bit};DBQ=SERVER_ADDRESS;Uid=XXX;Pwd=XXX;"
oCn.Open strConn

If oCn.State = adStateOpen Then
    Set GetNewConnection = oCn
End If
End Function
```

The entry in Event Viewer is:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.10730.20102, time stamp: 0x5b938e29
Faulting module name: SQORA32.DLL, version: 12.2.0.1, time stamp: 0x58a24eba
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000381b2
Faulting process id: 0x28cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d73226e4ff39f4
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\app\client\product\12.2.0\client_1\SQORA32.DLL
Report Id: 6b6153b3-9e1a-11eb-a325-005056ab5187
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Is `screenshot` really a `varchar2` parameter that takes a directory path?  Unless the directory path is on the server's file system, which would seem odd, the procedure can't read the file at that path.

Comment: Yes.  Screenshot is a varchar2 that is just accepting the path.

Comment: Just to add to this, as a test, I setup another stored procedure that has one string input and one string output (pretty much hello world), and I get the same results where is crashes.

Comment: Where is the code that sets up the connection?

Comment: I just updated the original post to include.  Thanks!  I have also tried different versions of ADO.  I am now using ADO6.

Comment: Are you sure that `oCn.State = adStateOpen`?  Or is there an issue opening the connection?

Comment: Yes.  To test, I swapped out the stores procedure call to simply retrieve data and everything was fine.